# Mac OS X linking .so file to dynamic library

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost

I'm trying to build a python package that is dependent on several libraries including boost, boost-python, and fftw. I am able to compile the package without any errors, but when I try to run the program with the `steme --help` command, I get an error:

```
2016-08-11 15:07:55,571:ERROR: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/<>/.ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/STEME-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/stempy/_release_build/_index.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6python6detail13current_scopeE
  Referenced from: /Users/<>/.ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/STEME-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/stempy/_release_build/_index.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/<>/.ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/STEME-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/stempy/_release_build/_index.so
```

My understanding is the the file `_index.so` is looking for the symbol `__ZN5boost6python6detail13current_scopeE` but can't find it. Next I checked what libraries are linked to the `_index.so` file using `otool -L`:

```
/Users/<>/.ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/STEME-1.9.1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/stempy/_release_build/_index.so:
    /usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3.3.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Based on this, what I think is happening is that the `boost-python` dynamic library was not properly linked to `_index.so` during compilation. To check that I ran `nm -g` on the `boost-python` dylibs (which were installed using `brew`, along with the other mentioned dependencies). The missing symbol was found in the `libboost_python.dylib` file:

`0000000000031d08 S __ZN5boost6python6detail13current_scopeE`

So, my next question is, how do I link the `libboost_python.dylib` file (located at `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.61.0/lib`) to the `_index.so` file? Will that even fix the problem? Is there some compiler flag that I need to set to make sure the build is properly linked?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.61.0/lib` in your path when you launch the binary. Something like

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.61.0/lib
$ ./your-binary
```

The link to the library is there otherwise you could not have found it via `otool`. I think that the program is not finding the shared library as it cannot be found in the PATH.

This error seems very similar to the "DDL not found" error type in windows, which can be fixed by supplying the DDL either in the current dir or in the PATH.

Comment: I would also comment that `otool` did not find the link to the `boost-python` library

Comment: How are you linking the boost-python library? (build tool, like CMake, Make, ...)

Comment: I have supplied the path to the boost-python library as a variable in the configuration before calling `python setup.py build`. In addition, I'm not sure why the program would successfully compile but not have the proper link to the dylib file

Comment: I assume you are working off this guide correct? https://pythonhosted.org/STEME/getting_started.html#install-steme

Comment: I am looking at the extract: "In fact, you may pass the options --update-user and --update-global to configure, and it will automatically update these files for you."

Try to add the --update-global flag when you invoke configure.py this might put the path to the library in the correct location for the python runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120744/discussion-between-ramses728-and-matt).